# Want to use Redis as an events statistics store

Tags: redis

I am really interested in Redis, I have an idea and wanted to know if it is a suitable use case, or if it is not any other suggestions on a data store. Also any tips on storing the data would be appreciated.

My idea is just a simple event system so an event happens and it is stored in redis as follows

Key | Value 
[unixtimestamp]:[system]:[event] | [result]

The data could be anything sales, impressions, errors, api response times, page load times any real time analytics. I then want to be able to make graphs based on that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an ideal design because it won't support your read pattern effectively and it will probably wasteful in terms of RAM if your [result] is short/small. Instead, look into using Redis' [sorted sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) with the timestamp as score, in the following fashion:

```
ZADD [system]:[event] [timestamp] [result]
```

Note that set members have to be unique so if [result]'s cardinality is low, make it unique by concatenating the timestamp to it (and filtering it out when you graph), i.e.:

```
ZADD [system]:[event] [timestamp] [result]:[timestamp]
```

This way you'll be able to fetch ranges of measurements by calling ZRANGEBYSCORE and graphing the results.

Comment: If I am adding 100s or 1000s of records per minute would I need to add some other type of unique id other than time?

Comment: Since the timestamp resolution is 1sec, if there's a chance that you'll have the same result for that system/event, then yes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am still having a hard time getting my head around around Redis. If I wanted to store a more complex key like a hash or maybe just some json. eg: {page: x, loadtime: y} and I wanted to group or query by that data, would that have to be in my app layer or can redis help here too

Comment: I'd love to help but since that's a different question lets open a new one here or if you want to touch heads feel free to email me directly: itamar at redislabs dot com

Comment: Thanks I added another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497539/redis-design-events-statistics-store?noredirect=1#comment41635643_26497539