# Get data by time range from Redis

Tags: php, redis, date-range, nosql

I have MySQL table *elements_info* with fields:

element_id | price | time_start | time and

To get *element_id* and *price* fields from MySQL i use query:

```
SELECT * FROM `elements_info` WHERE 1447141365 BETWEEN time_start AND time_end;
```

Where *1447141365* - current timestamp.

Can I store this structure in **Redis** (maybe zset)?
Or maybe I should choose another NoSQL DB to get elements by time range?

Comment: Yes, a Zorted Set would work perfectly here. Here's something to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475557/want-to-use-redis-as-an-events-statistics-store/26475831#26475831

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! How can I store such structure in zset? I need to get element_id and price by timestamp which is between time_start & time_end...